# _spFriendlyUrlPageContextInfo undefined despite using managed metadata navigation

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model

I'm building a custom navigation solution using the JSOM in Sharepoint 2013.
I need to get the navigation term corresponding to the current page and I found [this question with a similar problem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94371/get-navigation-term-for-current-page-in-csom-javascript) and the top-voted answer suggested using `_spFriendlyUrlPageContextInfo`.

However, on my aspx page, the variable is undefined. What could be the reason, are there any good alternatives?
The site uses managed metadata navigation.

Answer (score 1):

The variable is undefined usually when the user is not logged in. I wrote this function to populate the same variable from data existing on the page:

```
function setFriendlyUrlPageContextInfo() {
    if (typeof (_spFriendlyUrlPageContextInfo) == "undefined" || _spFriendlyUrlPageContextInfo == null) {
        var formaction = null;
        if (_spOriginalFormAction != "undefined" && _spOriginalFormAction != null) {
            formaction = _spOriginalFormAction;
        } else {
            formaction = document.forms.length > 0 ? document.forms[0].action : null;
        }
        if (formaction) {
            var termName = null;
            var termNameMatches = (/\/([^\/]+)\?/ig).exec(formaction);
            if (termNameMatches && termNameMatches.length > 1) {
                termName = termNameMatches[1];
            }
            var termId = null;
            var termIdMatches = (/TermId=([^\&]+)(?:\&|$)/ig).exec(formaction);
            if (termIdMatches && termIdMatches.length > 1) {
                termId = termIdMatches[1];
            }
            if (termName && termId) {
                _spFriendlyUrlPageContextInfo = {
                    title: termName,
                    termId: termId
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```